# title is duplicated in metadata when using --replace-in-metadata

Tags: python, yt-dlp

I am writing a Python script which reads a CSV file containing video URLs + plus certain metadata fields I want to specify manually, and downloads the MP3s from those videos and sets the metadata fields. I want the script to insert the "Title" value from the CSV to the "title" metadata field in the MP3, and I'm using the --replace-in-metadata option to accomplish that. My code works to download the videos and convert them, but the in the MP3 metadata field, the value in Title gets written twice. For instance, one of the video titles in the CSV is "The 3 Karma" In the MP3 file, the title metadata field is set to "The 3 KarmaThe 3 Karma". Below are the contents of my csv file:

```
URL,Title,Album,Artist
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPmRVBa0NF4,The 3 Karma,Shadow Hearts: Covenant,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UigzN-4JR14,Simple and Clean,Kingdom Hearts,Utada Hikaru
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1Bd02CxVv0,An Earnest Desire of Grey,Radiant Historia,Yoko Shimomura
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjPWTEtuv74,Godsibb,Xenosaga Episode III: Also Spach Zarathustra,Yuki Kajiura
```

Here is my code, with the csv filepath taken out:

```
import subprocess
import csv

#Open CSV file
urlList = open()#ADD CSV FILEPATH IN PARENTHESES#
reader = csv.DictReader(urlList)
#For each row, construct yt-dlp command
for row in reader:
    args = ['yt-dlp', '-x', '--audio-format', 'mp3', '--embed-thumbnail', '--add-metadata']
    args.append('-P')
    args.append('C:\\Users\mattw\Documents\Python Stuff\Music\\' + row['Album'].replace(":","") + '\\')
    args.append('-o')
    args.append(row['Title'].replace(":","") + '.%(ext)s')
    args.append('--replace-in-metadata')
    args.append('title')
    args.append('.*')
    args.append(row['Title'])
    args.append(row['URL'])
    result = subprocess.run(args)
    print(format(result.stdout))
    print(format(result.args))
```

As an example, here are the args generated by the "The 3 Karma" row:

```
['yt-dlp', '-x', '--audio-format', 'mp3', '--embed-thumbnail', '--add-metadata', '-P', 'C:\\Users\\mattw\\Documents\\Python Stuff\\Music\\Shadow Hearts Covenant\\', '-o', 'The 3 Karma.%(ext)s', '--replace-in-metadata', 'title', '.*', 'The 3 Karma', '--parse-metadata', 'album:%(album|Shadow Hearts: Covenant)s', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPmRVBa0NF4']
```

I've read the documentation on the yt-dlp GitHub multiple times, but it's flying over my head. It seems more tailored to formatting metadata fields rather than replacing them wholesale. I tried using --parse-metadata instead, but I don't understand how to format it properly. I've searched for other threads on this problem, but few exist and none seem to involve replacing the whole field with a manually specified value. Some threads I searched:
https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues/5383

[Set metadata based on the output filename in yt-dlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347719/set-metadata-based-on-the-output-filename-in-yt-dlp)

Edit:
I haven't figured out why the --add-metadata option is duplicating, but I found a superior workaround. Now I'm using --postprocessor-args to set each field. This doesn't cause duplication, and it has the advantage of being able to set fields that don't appear in the original video's JSON. Example:

```
'--postprocessor-args', 'ffmpeg: -metadata title="An Earnest Desire of Grey" -metadata album="Radiant Historia" -metadata artist="Yoko Shimomura" -metadata publisher="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1Bd02CxVv0"'
```